# How to deserialize namespaces into classes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization, xml-namespaces

I need to deserialize a XML such as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ns0:Info xmlns:ns0="http://www.x.com/">
 <Name>Anthony</Name>
 <Job>Developer</Job>
</ns0:Info>
```

I have created the class from an XSD document using the XSD tool but it does not recognize the NAMESPACES. How could I do it? How can I alter the class in order to recognize them? Should I alter the XSD instead?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems same as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465825/how-to-deserialize-an-xml-doc-with-a-prefixed-namespace-but-no-ns-prefixed-elemen) even xml!

Comment: I copied a simple example... It is not the same problem

Comment: If it's not the same problem, please explain why the answers given to that question don't work for you.

Comment: The problem is that with the generated xsd it does not recognize tags with namespaces into them, such as <ns0:Info>, it says (ns0 is a not recognized namespace), it only works for simple tags <Info> for example. So I would like to know how to change the generated class or the XSD to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

//Add an empty namespace and empty value
ns.Add("", "");

//Create the serializer
XmlSerializer slz = new XmlSerializer(someType);

//Serialize the object with our own namespaces (notice the overload)
slz.Serialize(myXmlTextWriter, someObject, ns);
```

Comment: Sshebly the problem is when deserializing. I know it is possible to serialize by adding the namespaces, but I don't know how to do the inverse operation.