# .Net (C#) cannot deserialize Java web service response

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wsdl

I am consuming java based web service from .Net application. The problem arise, when I got deserialized response from the web service, some of the fields in response comes with null values, but if I look at xml response, response has its proper values. So I guess main problem is that .Net cannot deserialize response properly. [Here is WSDL](http://t1-argus.vetrf.ru/api/argus/services/EnterpriseService?wsdl), the method I am using is "GetForeignEnterpriseList".

XML Response is

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
  <S:Body>
    <ns6:getForeignEnterpriseListResponse xmlns="http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/base" xmlns:ns2="http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/argus" xmlns:ns3="http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/institutions" xmlns:ns4="http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/ikar" xmlns:ns5="http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/base/register" xmlns:ns6="http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/argus/enterprise/ws-definitions" xmlns:ns7="http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/argus/ws-definitions">
      <ns2:enterpriseList offset="0" total="14058" count="1">
        <ns2:enterprise>
          <uuid>06e4a78e-053d-11e1-99b4-d8d385fbc9e8</uuid>
          <guid>cb1483ab-2c7d-db46-445c-09849ae9b761</guid>
          <active>true</active>
          <last>true</last>
          <status>100</status>
          <createDate>2009-10-08T12:50:47+04:00</createDate>
          <updateDate>2009-10-08T12:50:47+04:00</updateDate>
          <ns2:name>Cargill Meat Solutions Corporation</ns2:name>
          <ns2:englishName>
          </ns2:englishName>
          <ns2:activity>Убой КРС, разделка, хранение говядины</ns2:activity>
          <ns2:englishActivity>Cattle slaughter, Beef cutting, Beef storage</ns2:englishActivity>
          <ns4:address>
            <ns4:addressView>Friona</ns4:addressView>
            <ns4:enAddressView>
            </ns4:enAddressView>
          </ns4:address>
          <ns4:country>
            <uuid>91134526-4373-ec59-4a1e-e0e99bd50b7b</uuid>
            <guid>cac8a802-3c65-397d-895d-c0495bf6ea61</guid>
          </ns4:country>
          <ns4:region>
            <uuid>c7bad316-6564-787c-c502-6a9e8afdc093</uuid>
            <guid>bbee471c-0548-7190-cca9-5897eedbeac3</guid>
            <ns4:hasStreets>false</ns4:hasStreets>
          </ns4:region>
          <ns2:numberList>
            <ns2:enterpriseNumber>86 Е</ns2:enterpriseNumber>
          </ns2:numberList>
        </ns2:enterprise>
      </ns2:enterpriseList>
    </ns6:getForeignEnterpriseListResponse>
  </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

This is .Net generated class for enterprise node I need to get.

```html
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.18408")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/argus")]
    public partial class Enterprise : GenericVersioningEntity {
        
        private string nameField;
        
        private string englishNameField;
        
        private string activityField;
        
        private string englishActivityField;
        
        private Address addressField;
        
        private Country countryField;
        
        private Region regionField;
        
        private District districtField;
        
        private string[] numberListField;
        
        private string typeField;
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
        public string name {
            get {
                return this.nameField;
            }
            set {
                this.nameField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("name");
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]
        public string englishName {
            get {
                return this.englishNameField;
            }
            set {
                this.englishNameField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("englishName");
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=2)]
        public string activity {
            get {
                return this.activityField;
            }
            set {
                this.activityField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("activity");
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=3)]
        public string englishActivity {
            get {
                return this.englishActivityField;
            }
            set {
                this.englishActivityField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("englishActivity");
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=4)]
        public Address address {
            get {
                return this.addressField;
            }
            set {
                this.addressField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("address");
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=5)]
        public Country country {
            get {
                return this.countryField;
            }
            set {
                this.countryField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("country");
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=6)]
        public Region region {
            get {
                return this.regionField;
            }
            set {
                this.regionField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("region");
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=7)]
        public District district {
            get {
                return this.districtField;
            }
            set {
                this.districtField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("district");
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Order=8)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("enterpriseNumber", IsNullable=false)]
        public string[] numberList {
            get {
                return this.numberListField;
            }
            set {
                this.numberListField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("numberList");
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="integer", Order=9)]
        public string type {
            get {
                return this.typeField;
            }
            set {
                this.typeField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("type");
            }
        }
    }
```

.Net cannot deserialize "address", "country", "region", "numberList" nodes.

And this is example of how .Net generated class for country node which comes as null.

```html
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.18408")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/ikar")]
    public partial class Country : GenericVersioningEntity {
        
        private string nameField;
        
        private string fullNameField;
        
        private string englishNameField;
        
        private string codeField;
        
        private string code3Field;
        
        private bool isRussiaField;
        
        private bool isRussiaFieldSpecified;
        
        private bool isCustomsUnionField;
        
        private bool isCustomsUnionFieldSpecified;
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
        public string name {
            get {
                return this.nameField;
            }
            set {
                this.nameField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("name");
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]
        public string fullName {
            get {
                return this.fullNameField;
            }
            set {
                this.fullNameField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("fullName");
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=2)]
        public string englishName {
            get {
                return this.englishNameField;
            }
            set {
                this.englishNameField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("englishName");
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=3)]
        public string code {
            get {
                return this.codeField;
            }
            set {
                this.codeField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("code");
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=4)]
        public string code3 {
            get {
                return this.code3Field;
            }
            set {
                this.code3Field = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("code3");
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=5)]
        public bool isRussia {
            get {
                return this.isRussiaField;
            }
            set {
                this.isRussiaField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("isRussia");
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
        public bool isRussiaSpecified {
            get {
                return this.isRussiaFieldSpecified;
            }
            set {
                this.isRussiaFieldSpecified = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("isRussiaSpecified");
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=6)]
        public bool isCustomsUnion {
            get {
                return this.isCustomsUnionField;
            }
            set {
                this.isCustomsUnionField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("isCustomsUnion");
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
        public bool isCustomsUnionSpecified {
            get {
                return this.isCustomsUnionFieldSpecified;
            }
            set {
                this.isCustomsUnionFieldSpecified = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("isCustomsUnionSpecified");
            }
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: .Net shouldn't have any issues, can we see how you formulate the serialization for the service?  We need that code, plus your link doesn't work.

Comment: Oh sorry. This is third party webservice that I have no control but have access to.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the xml namespaces, all of the ns2: , ns4: etc.

You could strip these out of the message text including the namespace declarations, hacky but quick. Or you could do it properly by including the names spaces in your object something like this

```
XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/")]
public class Enterprise
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/ikar")]
    public Address Address{ get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/ikar")]
    public Country Country { get; set; }

   ...
}

XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/ikar")]
public class Address
{
 ....    
}
```

havent tried this so is a guess, good luck!

Comment: this is a similar problem  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465825/how-to-deserialize-an-xml-doc-with-a-prefixed-namespace-but-no-ns-prefixed-eleme

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in interpretation of given wsdl by .Net. 
In WSDL fields of Country entity are described as

So main problem here is in interpretation of minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" attributes by .Net.

When soap response comes as

```html
<ns4:country>
 <uuid>91134526-4373-ec59-4a1e-e0e99bd50b7b</uuid>
 <guid>cac8a802-3c65-397d-895d-c0495bf6ea61</guid>
</ns4:country>
```

.Net can’t deserialize it properly and gives country object as null. And i can't access fields of 'country' object. I think it happens because .Net expects to receive "country" object with all fields populated, but there are only two fields. 
But when I consume web service by NetBeans, 'country' object comes with all fields. Those fields are null except uuid and guid fields.

Currently I copied wsdl and all xsd files, and want to modify them for .Net proper serialization.
But next problem is how to edit them correctly?